# More efficient for loop based on check

Tags: r

I've written a `for` loop that does some checks and returns a 0 or 1 based on the results.  However, running this on a large data set is going to take a long time (Left overnight and still running in the morning).  Any idea on how to make this more efficient with `dplyr` or another tool?  Thanks

Here's some test data :

```
tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), fyear = c("1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", 
"1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1975", "1975", "1975", 
"1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975"
), datadate = c(19711231L, 19710129L, 19710226L, 19710331L, 19710430L, 
19710528L, 19710630L, 19710730L, 19710831L, 19710930L, 19711029L, 
19711130L, 19721231L, 19720131L, 19720229L, 19720330L, 19720428L, 
19720531L, 19720630L, 19720731L, 19720831L, 19720929L, 19721031L, 
19721130L, 19721229L, 19731231L, 19730131L, 19730228L, 19730330L, 
19730430L, 19730531L, 19730629L, 19730731L, 19730831L, 19730928L, 
19731031L, 19731130L, 19741231L, 19740131L, 19740228L, 19740329L, 
19740430L, 19740531L, 19740628L, 19740731L, 19740830L, 19740930L, 
19741031L, 19741129L, 19751231L, 19750131L, 19750228L, 19750331L, 
19750430L, 19750530L, 19750630L, 19750731L, 19750829L, 19750930L, 
19751031L), month = c("12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "12", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", 
"03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10")), .Names = c("cusip", 
"fyear", "datadate", "month"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For loop :

```
for(i in min(tdata$cusip):max(tdata$cusip)){ 
    for (j in min(tdata$fyear):max(tdata$fyear)) {
      monthcheck <- filter(tdata, cusip == i & (fyear == j-1 | fyear == j-2 | fyear == j-3 | fyear == j-4))
      if((length(monthcheck$month) / 60) >= 0.4) tdata$check[tdata$cusip == i & tdata$fyear ==  j] <- 1
}}
```

This returns a 1 for 1973-1975 because the checks pass.  Is there a way to make this `for` loop more efficient as this is going to take a while to run on a large dataset?

Edit : Explanation of for loop

For each unique ID (cusip) and for each year (fyear) grab the previous 4 years of data using `select`, then count the number of observations and check whether or not it is greater than 40%.  If so, assign a 1 to `tdata$check` for the specific cusip.

The idea is to ensure there are at least 24 of 60 prior month observations for each unique id.

Comment: Can you explain in words what that `for` loop does?

Comment: @DavidArenburg see edit as I've outlined the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with grouping and lagging cumulative sums:

```
library(dplyr)

tdata %>%
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>%
  summarise(number = n(), share = n() / 60)  %>% 
  mutate( cum_y = lag(cumsum(share)), 
          cum_y4 = lag(cum_y, 4),
          last4 = ifelse(is.na(cum_y4), cum_y, cum_y - cum_y4),
          check = as.numeric( last4 >= 0.4 )
          ) %>%
  select(cusip, fyear, last4, check)
```

Explained:

1. Group by `fyear`, count observations and get `share` for a year
2. `cum_y` is a lagged cumulative sum of shares
3. `cum_y4` is a 4 years lagged `cum_y`
4. `last4` is the difference between `cum_y` and `cum_y4`
5. `check` is checking `last4`

#### Update

Joining with variables in original data:

```
... %>%
  left_join(tdata, by = c("cusip", "fyear"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't take into account unique id (cusip).  Would the code need to be changed to `group_by(cusip, fyear)`?

Comment: This works great thanks.  However, it's not returning all my variables on my larger dataset even after I've removed `select` at the end.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Because of group. If the variables are constant in cusip-fyear pair you can add them in the group_by list. If they are not, then use `left_join` on original data frame with observations with `by = c("cusip", "fyear")`.